# Ошибка при сборке maven

Tags: java, maven

Подскажите как убрать это предупреждение и как повлияет это на проект?

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Test/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Это предупреждение говорит вам о том, что `com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields` перестанет работать через полгода-год и лучше подыскать другую библиотеку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev эту библиотеку я не прописывал у себя в проекте ее подгружает зачем то сам maven

Comment: Затем подгружает, что она является зависимостью для одной из используемых вами библиотек.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как узнать в какой зависимости используется?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы не было этой ошибки нужно переопределить war plugin на более новый. Например:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```